# Mysql_real_escape_string обрезает строку как только видет символ & как обойти обрезание строки?

Tags: php, html, sql

имеется строка

> htpp://vk.com/slava?smartname='[first_name]'&smartphone='[phone_mobile]'&smartemail='[email]'&

но mysql_real_escape_string обрезает строку как только встречает &

> htpp://vk.com/slava?smartname='[first_name]'

**Как сделать чтобы символ(&) не обрезал?**

Comment: [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте экранирование символа, с помощью:

> \